# Does creating multiple instances of a Entity Container in Entity Framework make multiple connections

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

When using entity framework, if we create five separate objects of a single entity, does .NET make a separate connection to the database for each one or does it know enough to pool this into one single connection behind the scenes since it's the same Entity Container.

In the example below, would this create five separate connection, or just one since they both are an instance of dbEntity, thus using the same base Entity Container

```
'Do 5 row counts on a new instance of dbEntity each time
For I as integer = 1 to 5
     Dim ent as new dbEntity
     Dim count = ent.Table.Count()
Next
```

The reason I am asking is right now I am creating a single instance of dbEntity, but selecting dozens of rows from different tables.  The problem is if I want to update a row I selected from the table for local usable, but not save it to the database, I cannot do ent.SaveChanges or all changes get saved.

Example below:

```
Dim ent as new dbEnt 'Connect to the DB
Dim localOnly = ent.Table.First; 'Get the first row (we never want to save changes right now)
localOnly.Name = "John" 'I do not want to ever save this

'Update our settings
Dim settings = ent.Settings.First 'Get our settings row
settings.updated = NOW() 'Tell them we updated our settings now
ent.SaveChanges() ‘Since this is all one instance of dbEnt, localOnly gets saved even if we didn’t want it to
```

Now the solution would be to just create two instances of dbEnt.  The first would be for readOnly, that I never run SaveChanges on. The second would be for that specific row I want to save changes to.  My issue is, I am doing this on dozens of tables, so I don’t want to make dozens of connections if each time I create an instance of dbEnt a new connection is made to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not create multiple connections to the database, it will close the connection when you dispose of the `DBContext` object. But I would recommend that you do not use a single `DBContext` but rather create and dispose the `DBContext` in each method in you Data Access layer. For example:

```
public Function GetUsers() As IList(of UserDTO)
   Using DBContext As new SomeDataContext()
      return DBContext.TblUsers.Select(Function(u) new UserDTO(u.UserId, u.Username)).ToList()
   End Using
End Function
```

Do not expose `DBContext` or any of its entities outside of the DAL, use data transfer objects for that. (`UserDTO` class in this case)

Comment: Sorry if I did not mention it, but I am using an ADO.net Entity Data Model, so when I said a DBContext, I really meant the entity container of my model. I said DBContext since when I inspected it, it was inheriting that class.

That being said,  I am updating my question to match that.  So if I make multiple instances of this entity container, it does not connect multiple times?

Comment: One connection per Data context, if you are having one than there is one connection.

Comment: I am not sure if by doing the code I posted above, that is one or five, that is the problem.  If I create 15 copies of my Entity container, such as  dim currentEnt = new dbEnt()  is that 15 copies of the context or a single copy?

Since I am using the model generated by Visual Studio, I am not sure behind the scenes how this is handled, which is my underlining issue.  I would assume their is a connection pool somewhere that handles them all as one, I just want to confirm this

Comment: There is a pool but you still have to dispose of the context to mark the connection as free for re-use.